# Hiding username and password in Visual Studio Azure connection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

When making connections in Visual Studio to an Azure SQL Database, you have to write Username and Password for a user that has access to change the SQL database. How do I avoid this, since I'm worried preventing decompilation can only last for so long?

For example:

```
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:MYSERVER;Database=MYDATABASE;user id=MYIDHERE;password=MYPASSWORDHERE;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=15;");
```

So, long story short, how do I avoid entering **user id** and **password**?

It just doesn't feel safe since anyone could be able to add stuff to the database if they decompiled the program.

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx it explains how to encrypt your connection string

Comment: @AmaudF. Is that the only option? Plus, I'm not using XML but C#.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure SQL Database supports two types of authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-control-access): **SQL Authentication** that uses a username and password and **Azure AD Authentication** that uses identities managed by Azure Active Directory and is supported for managed and integrated domains. If you don’t want to use SQL Authentication, Azure AD Authentication is an alternative choice.

Besides, [Azure SQL Database firewalls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure) prevent all access to your database server until you specify which computers have permission using firewall rules. Client that gets username and password are not able to access your databases if it is not in ranges of acceptable IP addresses that you specify in firewall rules.

Comment: I need all IPs to be able to access the database at all times, but only with data I allow them to access through an app. How do I use AD Auth?

Comment: ``only with data I allow them to access through an app`` you want your app as only enter point for users access the database data, it's not necessary to enable all IPs, you could add a firewall rule for your web server to enable request coming from this server and prevent another computers/requests.

Comment: Han then which IPs do I enable? I'm not using an app service, it's just a normal UWP / Xamarin app. I want anyone with the app, or the other two Windows Forms apps to be able to access the databases.

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication for information about use Azure AD auth with SQL Azure Database

Comment: I need lots of "clients" should I say constantly reading and writing data to the database, while keeping it secure. Which would be better in this case?